# How to show that the operator $T(\{x_n\})=\{n x_n\}$ has closed graph?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, closed-graph

> Consider the subspace $$D=\left\{x\in \ell^2 \ \big|\ \sum_{n\in\mathbb N} n^2 |x_n|^2<\infty\right\}$$
> of $\ell^2$, and let $T:D\to\ell^2$ be defined by $T(\{x_n\})=\{n x_n\}$.

I need  hints to prove that the graph of $T$ is closed.

#### Progress

To show $T$ has a closed graph, we proceed as follow: Assume the sequence $\{x^{(m)} \}$ in $D$ such that $x^{(m)}$ converges to $x$ as $m\to\infty$   for some $x\in\ell^2$  and assume $Tx^{(m)}$ converges to $y$ as $m\to\infty$.  Our aim is to show $x\in\ell^2$ and $y=Tx$.

Comment: to show T is a closed graph, we proceed as follow: 
Assume the sequence {x^(m)} in D such that x^(m) converges to x as m goes to infinity, for some x in the space l^2 and assume Tx^m converges to y as m goes to infinity.

Our aim is to show x in the space l^2 and y=Tx

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to show $x\in \ell^2$; that is a part of the set-up.

The equality $y=Tx$ can be checked  component-wise: you need to check that $y_n=(Tx)_n$ for every $n$. That is, $y_n=nx_n$. Here are the two steps leading to the goal:

$$x_n =\lim_{m\to\infty} x^{(m)}_n\tag{1}$$
$$y_n =\lim_{m\to\infty} (Tx^{(m)})_n\tag{2}$$