# Is this operator bounded and closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, unbounded-operators, closed-graph

Let's define the subset of $\ell^2(\mathbb C)$
$$\mathcal D(A) = \left\{ {z \in {\ell ^2}\left( C \right),\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {k^2{{\left| {{z_k}} \right|}^2} < \infty } } \right\},$$
and define the linear operator on $\mathcal D(A)$ by
$$A\left( z \right) = \left( {{z_1},2{z_2},3{z_3}, \cdots } \right)$$ for $z\in \mathcal D(A)$.
I want to know if this operator is bounded and closed.

What I know:
If this operator is bounded, then it must hold that
$${\left\| {A\left( z \right)} \right\|_2} \le c{\left\| z \right\|_2}$$ for all $z \in \mathcal D(A)$. Also for closedness, an operator is closed if the closure of the graph is equal to the graph. If I denote the graph by $\Gamma(A)$, this implies $\Gamma(A)=\bar \Gamma \left( A \right)$. The graph is the tuple $\left( {z,A\left( z \right)} \right)$ for all $z \in \mathcal D(A)$.

How could I apply these results to my problem to deduce the above? any tips are welcomed.

Comment: for closedness, check the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066873/how-to-show-that-the-operator-t-x-n-n-x-n-has-closed-graph?rq=1

Comment: @Sam thanks. I will take a look. Any idea how to approach boundedness?

Comment: Try studying $e_n$.

Comment: @JackyChong what do you mean by that?

Comment: Sorry. I meant $e_n = (0, \ldots, 0, 1=z_n, 0, \ldots)$.

Comment: İ know what is $e_n$. What do you mean by studying it ?

Comment: Do you think the operator is bounded?

Comment: Yes, i think so.

Comment: Okay. Assume it is bounded and study the sequence $\{e_n\}$.

Comment: What is $\Vert e_n\Vert_{\ell^2}$ and what is $\Vert Ae_n\Vert_{\ell^2}$?

Comment: The first is obviously 1 ( the euclidian norm), the second is $\sqrt(n)$,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider $\left\| {A\left( z \right)} \right\|_2^2 = \left\| {\left( {{z_1},2{z_2},3{z_3}, \ldots } \right)} \right\|_2^2 = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {k{{\left| {{z_k}} \right|}^2}} $. However, $z \in \mathcal D(A)$, and therefore $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {{k^2}{{\left| {{z_k}} \right|}^2}}  < \infty $ and hence $\left\| {A\left( z \right)} \right\|_2^2 < \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {{k^2}{{\left| {{z_k}} \right|}^2}}  < \infty $, therefore notice that the mapping does not explode. Lets try to bound it now w.r.t $\left\| z \right\|_2^2$. Lets consider $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {{k^2}{{\left| {{z_k}} \right|}^2}}  = \alpha  < \infty $. Remember that if a series converges, then the sequence of terms converges to  0, i.e., $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } {k^2}{\left| {{z_k}} \right|^2} = 0$. Similarly, $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } {k}{\left| {{z_k}} \right|^2} = 0$. Therefore, we can select large enough $N$ such that
$$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {k{{\left| {{z_k}} \right|}^2}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^N {k{{\left| {{z_k}} \right|}^2}}  + \sum\limits_{k = N + 1}^\infty  {k{{\left| {{z_k}} \right|}^2}}  \le \sum\limits_{k = 1}^N {k{{\left| {{z_k}} \right|}^2}}  + \varepsilon  \le \\2\sum\limits_{k = 1}^N {k{{\left| {{z_k}} \right|}^2}}. $$

The last inequality holds since $\varepsilon  \ll \sum\limits_{k = 1}^N {k{{\left| {{z_k}} \right|}^2}} $ by assumption. Now, notice that
$$\left\| {A\left( z \right)} \right\|_2^2 = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {k{{\left| {{z_k}} \right|}^2}}  \le 2\sum\limits_{k = 1}^N {k{{\left| {{z_k}} \right|}^2}}  \le 2\sum\limits_{k = 1}^N {N{{\left| {{z_k}} \right|}^2}}  \le 2N\sum\limits_{k = 1}^N {{{\left| {{z_k}} \right|}^2}}  \le 2N\left\| z \right\|_2^2$$

Therefore we proved that ${\left\| {A\left( z \right)} \right\|_2} \le \sqrt {2N} {\left\| z \right\|_2}$, so we conclude the operator is bounded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is very clear :D.

Comment: you are welcome, happy to help.